# Convert row wise data into column wise data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a data of subject wise students marks in rows. I want it to be converted into column wise per each student.

I have gone through Stack overflow and saw few solutions and tried those, but none of those are helping or I'm not executing those properly.

Input:

```
 UID     SUBJECT     MARKS
16001   Chemistry   45
16001   CS          52
16001   English     28    
16002   Chemistry   25
16002   CS          25
16002   English     50
16011   Biology     25
16011   Chemistry   30
16011   English     40
16011   Physics     50

Expected Output
 UID       Maths    Physics  Chemistry Biology   CS   English
 16001      -        -       45         -        52     28
 16002      -        -       25         -        25     50
 16011      -        50      30         25       -      40

Query Written
select uid, 
  (case when subject='Maths' then Marks else '-' end) Maths,
  (case when subject='Physics' then Marks else '-' end) Physics,
  (case when subject='Chemistry' then Marks else '-' end) Chemistry,
  (case when subject='Biology' then Marks else '-' end) Biology,
  (case when subject='CS' then Marks else '-' end) CS,
  (case when subject='English' then Marks else '-' end) English
  from subWiseMarks
group by uid;

Output I'm getting
 UID       Maths    Physics  Chemistry Biology   CS   English
 16001      -        -       45         -        -      -
 16002      -        -       25         -        -      -
 16003      -        -       42         -        -      -
 16011      -        -       -          25       -      -
```

Which means I'm getting only the first entry of each student. What is the mistake in this code. Any help is appreciated. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - you've to use max/min aggregation here

```
select uid, 
  max(case when subject='Maths' then Marks else '-' end) Maths,
  max(case when subject='Physics' then Marks else '-' end) Physics,
  max(case when subject='Chemistry' then Marks else '-' end) Chemistry,
  max(case when subject='Biology' then Marks else '-' end) Biology,
  max(case when subject='CS' then Marks else '-' end) CS,
  max(case when subject='English' then Marks else '-' end) English
  from subWiseMarks
group by uid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple with multiple table joins to the same table. This should be well optimized by MySql.

*Written on the fly, not tested but this should work.*

```
SELECT
  id.UID     UID,
  math.marks Maths,
  phys.marks Pysics,
  bio.marks  Biology,
  cs.marks   CS,
  engl.marks English

FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT UID FROM subWiseMarks) id
LEFT JOIN subWiseMarks math
LEFT JOIN subWiseMarks phys  USING(UID)
LEFT JOIN subWiseMarks chem  USING(UID)
LEFT JOIN subWiseMarks bio   USING(UID)
LEFT JOIN subWiseMarks cs    USING(UID)
LEFT JOIN subWiseMarks engl  USING(UID)
WHERE math.SUBJECT = 'Maths'
AND   phys.SUBJECT = 'Physics'
AND   phys.SUBJECT = 'Chemistry'
AND   phys.SUBJECT = 'Biology'
AND   phys.SUBJECT = 'CS'
AND   phys.SUBJECT = 'English'
;
```

Comment: I have 4 more subjects, which I didn't post in question. It makes my query too lengthy. Thank-you for your response.